# List vcpkg packages in manifest mode

Tags: vcpkg

In classic mode you can run `vcpkg list` to see all installed packages. What is the equivalent in manifest mode?

*vcpkg.json* does not specify versions, so I would like to see what versions I actually got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [--x-install-root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/commands/common-options#install-root).
Given that default value (`vcpkg_installed`) was used during install it should be:

```
vcpkg list --x-install-root=<path-to-vcpkg-json>\vcpkg_installed\<triplet>
```

Comment: That option works. Digging into it a bit I noticed that the vcpkg.cmake used as the cmake toolchain file points to `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg_installed"`, so thats the path I had to use.